# Securing a resource in Web Server

Tags: apache

I have a file (or set of files under a directory) published on my web server. Each of this resource needs to be access-protected based on the user's credentials and authority.

The authorization details are stored in a DB, so I need to make a call to the Java code in application server to determine the access.

Everytime the user hits this particular path in the webserver, I need to ensure s/he has access to the requested resource by, ensuring he is logged in and has the necessary priveleges to access this resource.

The webserver is apache - Can you please point me to the settings in apache that allows me to secure resource access using the above logic?

Thanks for the suggestions to correct the Tag and the Question!:

1. My Web Server is Apache HTTPD
2. Agree that this is not a Java Question: The only reason why I am bringing the Java perspective, is that I am most likely going to use some Java POJOs to go and check for user authorization for a particular directory that is stored in the DB - That is unless there is a trick in the apache httpd configuration that goes and checks the DB automatically - something similar to the one that is pointed out here...At the end of the it, I need to check if a particular user (authenticated previously by the Single Sign On Server (Sun access manager)) has access to a particular directory (user mapping to directory stored in the DB) and protect the resources under the directory accordingly.

Please let me know if that clarifies.

Comment: Your question is confusing. When you said "Apache", do you really mean "[Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org)", which has completely nothing to do with Java/Java EE as you tagged on the question, or do you mean "[Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org)", which is a JSP/Servlet container which happen to implement parts of Java EE? The current answer of user2304702 clearly assumes "Apache HTTPD" as that's often being assumed when someone says "Apache" in an overgeneralized way ("Apache" is the name of a software company, not a product, but the PHP folks overgeneralize "Apache HTTPD" as such).

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure why this is tagged with java - unless your db structure is VERY sepcific, you might able to get it done with apache authz and authn:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html

or, for an ovierview:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html